# Safe using user input as key_name?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to use a string that was input by the user in a web form as part of a key name:

```
user_input = self.request.POST.get('foo')
if user_input:
  foo = db.get_or_insert(db.Key('Foo', user_input[:100], parent=my_parent))
```

Is this safe? Or should I do some inexpensive encoding or hash? If yes, which one?

Comment: if self.request.POST['foo'] doesn't exist you'll have an exception

Comment: I wanted to keep the example short. Of course I do it differently in real code, including encoding, length check and other verification. The question is focused on using the incoming string as key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's safe as long as you don't care about a malicious user filling up your database with junk. `get_or_insert` won't let them overwrite existing entries, just add new ones.

Make sure you limit it's length (both in the UI and after it's been recieved), even if you do no other validation on it, so at least they can't just give you crazy big keys either to fill up the database quickly or to crash your app.

Edit: You just commented that you do, in fact, verify that it's a reasonable key. In that case, yes, it's safe.

Keep in mind that the user can probably still figure out what key are already in your database, based on how long it takes you to respond to what they've provided, and you still need to make sure they're authorized to see whatever content they request, or limit them to a small number of requests to they can't just brute-force retrieve all the information linked to the keys you're generating.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I will consider all the above.

Comment: Also, not all key names are valid. Apart from length limitations, key names starting and ending with `__` are reserved - eg, `__key__`.